# google search using bs4,python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to pick up the address of "[Spotlight 29 casino address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZCiC.jpg)" through Google search in the python script. Why isn't my code working?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from googlesearch import search
import urllib.request
import datetime
article='spotlight 29 casino address'
url1 ='https://www.google.co.in/#q='+article
content1 = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(content1,'lxml')
#print(soup1.prettify())
div1 = soup1.find('div', {'class':'Z0LcW'}) #get the div where it's located
# print (datetime.datetime.now(), 'street address:  ' , div1.text)
print (div1)
```

[*Pastebin Link*](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2VD6JySkhr/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get google search result. [Selenium with Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is more simple way.

below is simple code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chromedriver = '/xxx/chromedriver' #xxx is chromedriver in your installed path
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)

article='spotlight 29 casino address'
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/#q="+urllib.parse.quote(article))
# driver.page_source  <-- html source, you can parser it later.
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div',{'class':'Z0LcW'})
print(div.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: This one showing error in my case.i didn't get this.what can i do ?   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver) #chromedriver in your installed path

Comment: download [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) in your computer, chromedriver = 'file path in your computer.'

Comment: Oh!! Sorry my mistake I haven't noticed that before. after giving the file path it worked.  Thank you @chifu lin

Comment: Can it be done without opening the browser? Just want to print the output in terminal @chifu lin

Comment: use headless mode. I modify my code, you can reference.

Comment: working for a single input(one article search). but when I'm trying to take input article from an input file it's showing `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: please check once my [CODE](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tw5h5sgCrK/) and the [ERROR](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qSw56pqVHD/) that is showing @chifu lin

Comment: Maybe you can try it [code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7NVwvgjFqM/), move driver.quit( ) to outside. @Ruman_Hossain

Answer (score 0):

Google uses javascript rendering for that purpose, that's why you don't receive that div with urllib.request.urlopen.

As solution you can use selenium - python library for emulating browser. Install it using 'pip install selenium' console command, then code like this shall work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


article = 'spotlight 29 casino address'
url = 'https://www.google.co.in/#q=' + article
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

div = html.find('div', {'class': 'Z0LcW'})
print(div.text)
```

Comment: I have already installed selenium but still, it's showing error in line `driver = webdriver.Firefox() ` @djangomaster

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RUMAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\RUMAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\RUMAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

`

Comment: `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. `

Comment: geckdriver needs to be installed for firefox?

Comment: ah, okay, it seems you have no Firefox installed in your system. You can use any other browser, for example to use webdriver.Ie() instead of Firefox.
You can check this page for more info:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

The important thing is that web browser which you will use must be executable in your OS.

Comment: ya, geckodriver also needed, it seems. I have it installed on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

You were getting an empty `div` because if you were using `requests` library the default `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus your request is being blocked by Google (*in this case*) and you received a different HTML with different elements. `User-agent` fakes "real" user visit.

You can achieve it without `selenium` if the address was in HTML code (which in this case it is) by [passing `user-agent` into request `headers`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

```py
headers = {
  "User-agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

---

Here's code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Addres-from-Google-Search-python-bs4-requests):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=spotlight 29 casino address", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one(".sXLaOe").text)

# 46-200 Harrison Pl, Coachella, CA 92236
```

---

P.S. There's a [dedicated web scraping blog](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) of mine. If you need to parse search engines, have a try using [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.